# ¿Como implemento Passport en angular 2.0 y nodeJs?

Tags: nodejs, angularjs-2.0, express, passport

Realizo esta pregunta, porque ya hice alguna aplicación con auntenticación con estas tecnologías: MongoDb, Angular, NodeJs y Express. El caso es que he estado investigando sobre Passport, pero no consigo implementarlo en nodeJs del todo y mucho menos me hago una idea de como será meterlo con angular luego. 
Con lo cual esa es mi pregunta ¿ Como se implementa ?. ¿Hay algún sitio donde pueda sacar algo de información, a parte de las documentaciones de internet?. 
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Aquí te dejo un enlace para la implementación de Passport basada en Bearer Token sobre Node.js. https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-http-bearer-example

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aportación dddenis. Te lo agradezco de veras, pero hay algo que no acabo de entender, el caso es que lo que he intentado hacer yo para implementarlo me ha llevado mucho más codigo... y creo que he montado un lio bastante grande. Muchos de los ejemplos que he visto carecian de modularidad, o al menos me lo ha parecido a mi, y la verdad es que no se por donde atajarlo, me estoy quedando un poco mosca con el asunto. Estoy echando un vistazo a tu aportación a ver si esclarece algo. Muchas gracias!!!

Comment: Deberias dejarnos el codigo de lo que has intentado por lo menos, para ver que tiene mal o en que se puede mejorar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui esta un ejemplo de como lo he implementado varias veces, espero que te sea de ayuda, pero la documentacion en internet esta muy buena ;)

#### ./local.js

Aqui implemento la authenticacion local, en un fichero aparte en caso de querer usar otras strategies, exporta un getStrategy que es el que su usa:

```
const passportLocal = require("passport-local");

function authenticateLocal(username, password, cb) {
    User.getById(username, (err, rec) => {
        if (err) {
            return cb(err);
        }
        if (rec === null) {
            return cb(null, false, { message: "User doesn't exist" });
        }
        if (!rec.verifyPasswordSync(password)) {
            return cb(null, false, { message: "Incorrect password" });
        }
        cb(null, { username, role: rec.role });
    });
}

function getStrategy() {
    return new passportLocal.Strategy(authenticateLocal);
}

exports.getStrategy = getStrategy;
```

#### passport.js

Aqui cargo las estrategias y exporta una funcion que usa para cargar passport

```
const passport = require("passport");
const local = require("./local");

function serialize(user, cb) {
    cb(null, user.username);
}

function deserialize(username, cb) {
    User.getById(username, (err, user) => {
        if (user) {
            cb(null, user);
        } else {
            cb(null, { username, role: "user" });
        }
    });
}

function configPassport(config) {
    passport.serializeUser(serialize);
    passport.deserializeUser(deserialize);
    passport.use(local.getStrategy());
}

exports.configPassport = configPassport;
```

#### app.js

Este es el modulo principal donde creas el router de express y le annades los middlewares

```
const passport = require("passport");
const myPassport = require("./passport");
const app = require("express")();

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "5mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: "5mb" }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(expressSession(expressSessionOptions));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

myPassport.configPassport(config);

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias de verdad, estuve mirando la documentación, pero me acababa haciendo algo de lío, porque tenía un poco la mosca detrás de la oreja, puesto que no estaba seguro de estar implantando passport de manera adecuada. Esto me orienta un poco más. Gracias.